On an Elementary Geometry Problem based on Triangles
We have to use only properties of parallel lines, angle sum property, congruent triangles and other basic geometric tools in order to prove the following proposition:

Suppose the straight line $AB$ of $\triangle ABC$ is bisected at $O$ and the perpendiculars $AX,BY,CZ$ are drawn to any straight line $OP$. Prove that:
(i) if $A,B$ are on the same side of $OP$ then $2CZ=AX+BY$.
(ii) if $A,B$ are on opposite sides of $OP$ then $2CZ=$ difference of $AX$ and $BY$.

I'd like to know how $A$ and $B$ can be on the same side of the line $OP$, since I cannot draw up any example, or intuition to help me understand it, for when I tried drawing it, I always saw that $A,B$ will be on the opposite sides of $OP$ since $O$ is on $AB$.
Source: Challenge and Thrill of Pre-College Mathematics, pg. 58 (Chapter 3, Exercise 3.3)
